# Query on TransparentProxy when using AppDomain

Tags: c#, appdomain, transparentproxy

I have a section of code which is passing an object across AppDomains and to make debugging easier I want to get rid of the TransparentProxy.

In the course of writing this sample, I discovered how to do it, but I have two very similar snippets of code which behave differently and I am not sure why.

I know the actuals values are correct, so this is just to aid debugging.

In the example below. I have a class Data which is initialised in the default domain and passed to Process which is running in another domain. If I attempt to clone the data structure using the static method it works, but using the instance method does and I don't quite understand why.

Can anyone explain?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain otherDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Test");

        var otherType = typeof(Process);
        var process = otherDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                 otherType.Assembly.FullName, otherType.FullName) as Process;

        Data d = new Data() { Info = "Hello" };
        process.SetData(d);
    }
}

public class Process : MarshalByRefObject
{

    public void SetData(Data data)
    {
        Data data1 = Data.Clone(data);
        Data data2 = data.Clone();

        Console.WriteLine(data1.Info); 
           // Debugger shows data1.Info as Hello

        Console.WriteLine(data2.Info); 
           // Outputs Hello, but Debugger shows data2 as     
           // System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy
    }

}

public class Data : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public string Info { get; set; }

    public Data Clone()
    {
        return Data.Clone(this);
    }

    public static Data Clone(Data old)
    {
        var clone = new Data();
        clone.Info = old.Info;
        return clone;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the static method from the other appdomain, the method is invoked in that appdomain and the new `Data` object is created in that appdomain. OTOH when you call the instance method, the call is marshaled to the object's original appdomain, so the clone `Data` object is created in the original appdomain. Then it is marshaled back to the other appdomain as a transparent proxy and appears there as a retern value.